# Alternative to mcrypt_encrypt?

Tags: php

As per the php 7.0 mcrypt_decrypt is deprecated.

I have following code.

```
$intSize= mcrypt_get_iv_size( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB );
$strSize = mcrypt_create_iv( $intSize, MCRYPT_RAND );
$strText = ( true == $boolTrimText ) ? trim( $strText ) : $strText;
$strResult = base64_encode( mcrypt_encrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, ( string ) $strKey, ( string ) $strText, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $strSize) );
```

Now we are getting

```
mcrypt_encrypt(): Key of size 0 not supported by this algorithm. Only keys of sizes 16, 24 or 32 supported
```

Any alternative to fix this warning?

Answer (score 4):

You should use openssl_encrypt.  here the link : http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go encryption/decryption have a look upon  this blog post
https://paragonie.com/white-paper/2015-secure-php-data-encryption it will tell you how to do it in proper way.

Alternative **http://php.net/manual/en/intro.openssl.php** 
This extension binds functions of » OpenSSL library for symmetric and asymmetric encryption and decryption.

Answer (score 1):

> Use String length `16` or `24` or `32` for variable `$strKey`

```
$strKey = 'YOUR_STRING'; #This string length should be 16 or 24 or 32
```

**Example :**

```
$strKey = '1234567890abcdef';                 #Length 16
$strKey = '1234567890abcdef76hgfrdg';         #Length 24
$strKey = '1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef'; #Length 32
```

Here is the details about [mcrypt_encrypt()](http://www.php.net/function.mcrypt-encrypt)

**Alternate Solutions :**

- [One way Hashing : crypt()](http://php.net/crypt)
- [OpenSSL : openssl_encrypt()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php)